# How to generate a year-quarter date from the command line?

Tags: command-line, date

I'm interested in outputting a representation of the current year-quarter, as well as the year-quarter for the previous month.

If today is 2012 January 1st, I'd like to get

```
2012q1
```

and

```
2011q4
```

as the respective outputs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One (kinda ugly) solution, using BASH arithmetic evaluation and the GNU `date` command:

```
echo $(date +%Y)q$(( ($(date +%-m)-1)/3+1 ))
echo $(date -d "-1 month" +%Y)q$(( ($(date -d "-1 month" +%-m)-1)/3+1 ))
```

Note that the `%-m` prevents `date` from 0-padding,
so this will still work for August and September.

Comment: Take $(...) instead of the deprecated backticks. They can easily be nested.

Comment: just be curious: why other answers use 4 as divisor.

Comment: @LiuYan刘研: Not sure.  There are 3 months in a quarter, so I think 3 is the correct divisor.  (Though that confused me at first, too.)

Comment: In September `%m` gives `09` which bash tries to interpret as octal due to the leading 0, so this throws an error that says `09: value too great for base (error token is "09")`. This can be fixed by disabling 0-padding by changing `%m` to `%-m`.

Answer (score 8):

All solutions that divide by four fail, for instance November:

```
% echo $(( 11/4+1 ))
3
```

The correct math would be:

```
$(( (m-1)/3 +1 ))
```

And as such, the quarter of current and previous month would be:

```
echo curr ${y}q$(((m-1)/3+1))
if [ $m = 1 ]; then
  echo prev $((y-1))q4
else
  echo prev ${y}q$(((m-2)/3+1))
fi
```

It's only twelve values to check, really…

```
% for m in {1..12}; do echo $m Q$(((m-1)/3+1)); done
1 Q1
2 Q1
3 Q1
4 Q2
5 Q2
6 Q2
7 Q3
8 Q3
9 Q3
10 Q4
11 Q4
12 Q4
```

Comment: +1 For "All solutions that divide by for fail". You're right! A quarter last for 3 months so the answers should be dividing by 3.

Answer (score 7):

Use my [dateutils](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/):

```
dconv 2012-01-01 -f '%Y%Q'
=>
  2012Q1
```

The `%q` and `%Q` flags are specific to dateutils, and return the quarter as number or in the form `Q<NUMBER>`.

Comment: `dconv now -f%Y%Q | tr Q q` if you really need that Q to be lower cased. (PS: we're packaging this in Fedora with `date` as the prefix instead of `d`, so "`dateconv`".)

Answer (score 4):

Probably, there is no direct solution.

You could use `awk` to avoid so many back-ticks.

```
date +"%Y %m" | awk '{q=int($2/4)+1; printf("%sq%s\n", $1, q);}'
date +"%Y %m" | awk '{q=int($2/4);y=$1;if (q==0){q=4;y=y-1;}; printf("%sq%s\n", y, q);}'
```

A `perl` solution would be cleaner but `perl` and `DateTime` are an heavy prerequisite.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DateTime;

my $today = DateTime->now;
print "today: " . $today->year . "q" . $today->quarter . "\n";

my $ago = DateTime->now->subtract( months=> 4);
print "some time ago: " . $ago->year . "q" . $ago->quarter . "\n"
```

Comment: Cool.  I like the first date/awk line, since it avoids calling (and passing parameters to) `date` twice.

Answer (score 4):

Split the format with date, calculate with awk, format with printf:

```sh
date +"%Y %m" | awk '{printf ("%4dq%1d\n", $1, ($2/4)+1)}'
```

Just date and bash:

```sh
echo $(date +%Yq)$(($(date +%m)/4+1))
```

Comment: The first line outputs `2012q0` which is incorrect.

Comment: @smokris: You're right - I picked the wrong line of my tests.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative, more as a curiosity. If GNU `awk` is involved, `date` is not needed:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print strftime("%Y")"q"int((strftime("%-m")-1)/3)+1}'
```

Answer (score 3):

Call `date` to retrieve the current year and month, and do the rest with arithmetic in the shell.

```
set $(date '+%Y %m');
this_quarter=${1}q$(($2 / 4 + 1))
if [ $2 -eq 1 ]; then
  last_month_quarter=$(($1 - 1))q4
else
  last_month_quarter=${1}q$((($2 - 1) / 4 + 1))
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Basic math for this quarter and last month's quarter:

```
y1=$(date +%Y)
m1=$(date +%m)
q1=$(( (m1 - 1) / 3 + 1))
y2=$(( y1 - (m1 == 1) ))
m2=$(( (m1 + 10) % 12 + 1 ))
q2=$(( (m2 - 1) / 3 + 1 ))
echo This Quarter: $((y1))q$q1
echo Last Month Quarter: $((y2))q$q2
```

The script uses the following parts:

1. $(unix-cmd) - evaluates a command in shell script
2. $((expr)) - evaluates a mathematical expression
3. remapping 1..12 -> 1..4 uses the following math (m-1)/3+1
4. evaluating the previous month uses modulo math

Answer (score 2):

Year-Quarter for this month

```
date +"%Yq$(expr $(expr $(date +%m) - 1) / 3 + 1)"
```

Year-Quarter for yester-month

```
date +"%Yq$(expr $(expr $(date -d '-1 month' +%m) - 1) / 3 + 1)"
```

Answer (score 2):

There is now the `%q` format to show this information.

From the [coreutils-8.26 release log](https://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=8745) from November 30, 2016:

> **New Features**
>   ...
>   date now accepts the %q format to output the quarter of the year.

And yes it works!

```
$ date "+%q"
4
$ date "+%Yq%q"
2016q4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the *fiscal* 13-week quarter that's based on the ISO week calendar, then the new handy %q isn't going to work, sadly. Here's a version of @manatwork's dateless solution with awk/strftime.

```
awk 'BEGIN{$x=int((strftime("%V")-1)/13)+1;print strftime("%G")"q"($x>4?4:$x)}'
```

The last little ternary bit handles the ISO leap-week years where the last quarter has 14 weeks.